Problem with Proposition 5.2.21 of Karatzas and Shreve
The following claim is made on page 297 of the text and I cannot figure out how it is true. In particular, global existence of the solution to the ODE
$$Y'(t) = f(W(t), Y(t))$$
is claimed when $f$ is only locally Lipschitz in the $Y$ argument. How is this possibly true? (See the excerpt below for the full detail. In case anyone is curious, one gets global Lipschitz continuity in $y$, with a constant that depends on $x$, in the case where $b(\cdot)$ is bounded, but this is NOT one of the assumptions of the proposition.)

For fixed $x$, $\rho(x,y)$ is thus Lipschitz-continuous and bounded in $y$. It follows that the product $f(x,y) \triangleq \rho(x,y) \cdot b(u(x,y))$ satisfies Lipschitz and growth conditions of the form
$$
|f(x,y_1) - f(x,y_2)| \leq L_k |y_1 - y_2|; \quad -k \leq x, y_1, y_2 \leq k \tag{2.40}
$$
$$
|f(x,y)| \leq K_1 + K_k |y|; \quad |x| \leq k, y \in \mathbb{R},\tag{2.41}
$$
where the constants $L_k$ and $K_k$ depend on $k$.

We may fix $\omega \in \Omega$ and let $Y_t(\omega)$ be the solution to the ordinary differential equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} Y_t(\omega) = f(W_t(\omega), Y_t(\omega)) \quad \text{with} \quad Y_0(\omega) = \xi(\omega).\tag{2.42}
$$

Such a solution exists globally and is unique because of $(2.40)$ and $(2.41)$.


It could be of help to read the original argument of Doss, p. 102.

Doss simply makes the statement that the ODE for $Y$ has a "maximal solution" (idk wat this even means), which is "in fact" defined for every $t \ge 0$. How he reaches this conclusion, is infuriatingly left unclear (see here for the excerpt: https://i.sstatic.net/2gvb87M6.png). I do not know any French, so apologies if I am missing something.

Doss' argument for that seems to me to start after 'En effet...' ('Indeed...')

He claims existence and then shows boundedness using Gronwall. But how do we know that the solution even exists up to time T?

Not clear to me. However, the author (and KS?) found it immediate for some reason. I think that at this point the question can be recast without even mentioning stochastic calculus or KS. This would likely make it reach a broader audience.

Yeah...I managed to figure it out. Define $T \equiv \sup{t \ge 0 : \text{ a solution exists on } [0,t]}$ and suppose $T < \infty$. From standard ODE theory, $T > 0$. Using the linear growth condition, one can show that the solution on $[0,T)$ is bounded (applying Gronwall's lemma). From the local Lipschitz condition on $f$, one can then claim the solution is Lipschitz on $[0,T)$ and hence may be extended to a limit at $T$. If one considers the IVP starting at $T$ with the same derivative $f$, this contradicts the assumption that $T$ was finite. Hence we have global existence
